# Working Animation broken by axis boundaries?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I re-created the Google Maps icon in Photoshop, and have a duplicate that I would like to take the place of the current image when the link wrapped around both is hovered over. I've used **position: absolute** to stack both img's on top of one another, and used a container to position it where I please. However, even with **overflow: hidden** in the container's css, the position is ruined.

**HTML MARKUP**

```
<div class="links_ct">
    <a class="link" href="#">
        <img class="back" src="files/img/gmaps2.png"/>
        <img class="front" src="files/img/gmaps.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.links_ct {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.front, .back {
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
}

.back {
    left: -45px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 500;
}

.front {
    z-index: 200;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
function head_link_hover() {
    $('.link').hover(function () {
        $('.back').animate({
            left: '+=45px'
        });
    }, function () {
        $('.back').animate({
            left: '-=45px'
        });
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    head_link_hover();
});
```

Basically, it animates properly, but on the complete wrong side of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I forgot to add **position: relative** to the container...oops.